# Returning result of pending Intent to the Activity that created it

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a notification from an Activity specifying the `requestCode` in

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context,requestCode,intent, flags)
```

I want to receive the result back to that Activity that created it

Is it possible to achieve this? If not then any other elegant way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need your pending intent to start your activity as it may be shutdown when the user touches the notification. So you can provide that activitie's start Intent with whatever extras you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
  }
```

I think this is the answer to this question. Please extend this method in the activity you called above.